# Get Second Child value from table of cell on click using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have designed Table with One row with title of month and cell that has inner table with separate rows and cell.I would like to show the content of any second cell of second table as modal box or alert dialog when clicked.

But now, it triggers alert box when both cell are clicked. But I would like to show / open alert dialog only when second cell is clicked.

Here is my table.

```js
$("table table tr").click(function() {
  alert($(this).children("td").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>



  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>January

 <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Do not show details of this cell</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Show details of this cell  when clicked</td>
          </tr>

        </table>

      </td>

    </tr>




   
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211766/discussion-on-question-by-pro-academy-get-second-child-value-from-table-of-cell).

Answer (score -1):

Use Css property of tr:nth-child(2) to target second cell value.

The full code is

```js
$('table table tr').eq(1).on('click', function(){ alert($(this).children("td").text());});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>



  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>January

 <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Do not show details of this cell</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td id="mytable">Show details of this cell  when clicked</td>
          </tr>

        </table>

      </td>

    </tr>




   
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```